# How to shift linked list to other using recursion

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

so this is the code i have to shift even nodes of a given linked list of strings to another list using recursion . here A is name of other linked list already declared in data members.
code will run untill temp means the original linked list is NULL or it's next is null.

I made length function for linked list and if
list is         `nor-> us->while->ok`
shifted list just prints `nor`

```
void movealternative(node<string>* temp, node<string>* newnode)
{
    if (temp == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    if (temp->next == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    if (length(temp) % 2 == 0) {

        if (newnode == NULL) {
            newnode = new node<string>;
            newnode->data = temp->next->data;
            // this if will execute once for second node
        }
        else {
            newnode = new node<string>;

            newnode->data = temp->next->data;
            newnode = newnode->next;

            if (temp->next->next != NULL) {
                temp->next = temp->next->next;
            }
        }
    }
    movealternative(temp->next, newnode);
    if (length(newnode) == 1) {
        A.head = newnode;
    }
}

void movealternative()
{
    node<string>* newnode = new node<string>;
    node<string>* temp = pass.head;

    movealternative(temp, newnode);
    A.print();
}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself. Do you know how to use a debugger? Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: Soo.... what is your question? Please, take the [tour] and read [ask] for a start.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- It will be inefficient to calculate the length of the list in each recursive call. That will make your algorithm O(n²).
- With `newnode = new node<string>;` the caller of `movealternative` will not see that change, as `newnode` is passed by value.
- Your code removes nodes without freeing their memory, leading to memory leaks.
- The caller of `movealternative` should not have to create a new node in order to start the process
- Since the task is really about *moving* nodes, there should not be a need to create new nodes. Instead you could take the removed node and inject it in the new list
- `pass` and `A` are apparently global variables: it is bad practice that they are not passed as arguments.
- It is not clear why `A.head = newnode;` should only happen when `newnode` has a length of 1. This assignment would be more an action for the caller to do.

Here is how I would do it (complete rewrite):

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {
public:
    int value;
    Node* next;
    Node(int value, Node* next): value(value), next(next) {};

    Node* pre(int value) {
        return new Node(value, this);
    }

    Node* moveAlternating() {
        if (next == nullptr) return nullptr;
        Node *alt = next;
        next = next->moveAlternating();
        return alt;
    }
};

class LinkedList {
public:
    Node* head = nullptr;

    void pre(int val) {
        head = new Node(val, head);
    }

    void print() {
        Node* node = head;
        while (node) {
            std::cout << node->value << " ";
            node = node->next;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    LinkedList* moveAlternating() {
        LinkedList *alt = new LinkedList();
        if (head != nullptr) alt->head = head->moveAlternating();
        return alt;
    }
};


int main() {
    // Create a input list
    LinkedList *lst = new LinkedList();
    for (int i = 7; i > 0; i--) lst->pre(i);
    std::cout << "input list: ";
    lst->print(); 

    // Call the algorithm
    LinkedList *alt = lst->moveAlternating();

    // Output results
    std::cout << "odds: ";
    lst->print(); 
    std::cout << "evens: ";
    alt->print();
}
```

This outputs:

```
input list: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
odds: 1 3 5 7 
evens: 2 4 6
```